# Выбор определенных пользователей

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать следующую функцию:
при создании голосования, отображается таблица - список всех пользователей, Можно выбрать всех или кого-то конкретного, кто будет видеть голосование. У нее есть 3 колонки - All(чекбоксы, выбрать всех или кого-то определенного), user ID, user name.
Табличку я наверное смогу сделать, а вот как быть с обработкой чекбоксов. После выделения и отправки формы, что должно происходить ? Запись массива из пользователей и как потом определять видимость ? И можно ли это сделать в одной таблице с голосованиями или нужно создать еще одну, специально для этого массива ?
Может быть есть конкретные примеры реализации такого функционала ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Как организовать форму

Тут вариантов миллион. Я бы сделал, наверное, примерно так: 
чекбоксы в вашей таблицы имеют примерно такой код

```
 <input type=checkbox name="users[{{user.id}}]" value=1>
```

где `{{user.id}}` - это id юзера, подставленный сюда через php.

При таком виде инпутов на сервере после отправки формы мы получим массив данных вида

```
$_GET['users'] = [
    102 => 1,
    104 => 1,
];
```

если выбрали только пользователей 102 и 104.

Просто перебираем массив и создаем записи в нашей таблице-посреднике, используя id голосования (его тоже получаем из формы, например из поля `<input type=hidden name="vote_id" value={{vote.id}}>`) и очередной id юзера. Код, упрощенно, такой:

```
$mysqli = new \mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");

$voteId = $_GET['vote_id'];

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO votes_users(vote, `user`) VALUES (?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $voteId, $userId);

foreach($_GET['users'] as $userId => $checked){
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
```

---

### Как организовать таблицы

Хранение данных я построил бы примерно так:

Таблица **votes**, сущности голосований:

```
__________________________
id  |  name               |
1   |  Первое голосование |
2   |  Второе голосование |
3   |  Третье голосование |
____|_____________________|
```

Таблица **users**, сущности юзеров:

```
__________________________
id  |  name               |
101 |  Jonny              |
102 |  Ivan               |
103 |  Alexey             |
104 |  Nikolai            |
____|_____________________|
```

Таблица **votes_users**, связи ManyToMany (многие ко многим), связи голосований с пользователями:

```
____________________
vote    |  user     |
1       |  102      |
1       |  104      |
2       |  101      |
2       |  102      |
3       |  102      |
3       |  103      |
3       |  104      |
________|___________|
```

Таким образом, нам всегда легко получить пользователей, которым доступны определенные голосования, как и наоборот - выбрать голосования по пользователю. 
К примеру, таким несложным запросом мы выберем всех пользователей, которые могут участвовать в голосовании с id=2:

```
SELECT
    u.*
FROM
    users u
JOIN votes_users vu ON vu.`user` = u.id
JOIN votes v ON vu.vote = v.id
WHERE v.id = 2
```

Comment: Зачем руками в базу лезть, если есть хороший инструмент в Yii2 для этого?
`$vote = new Vote(); $vote->userId = $id; $vote->save();`
Где `Vote` наследник `ActiveRecord` и содержит атрибут `userId` и прочие.

Comment: И полям таблицы лучше давать более очевидные названия, а не просто `vote` и `user`, т.к. потом можно и не вспомнить, что за `user` и почему там цифры. Взамен лучше дать название `voteId` и `userId`.

Comment: Я объяснил принцип, используя универсальный пример, без привязки к платформе. Следует заметить, что автор в вопросе не упомянул Yii, а метку я, каюсь, заметил только после. А уж user или user_id или userId - дело вкуса и не имеет функциональной разницы. Я у себя дал бы полю имя user_id.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын , да, в вопросе про yii не сказал, только метку. Но ход вашей идеи мне понятен. Спасибо всем за отзывы, буду пробовать.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын получилось, все работает. Спасибо вам!